# Both Thunderbird (52.4.0) & Outlook (15.39) on macOS High Sierra (10.13.1) won't open links in browser

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, macos-highsierra

When I click on a link in either Thunderbird or Outlook, it will briefly flash a new Chrome icon in my Dock, but when I switch over to Chrome from Thunderbird, there is only a blank new window - not a new window with the link loaded, or a new tab with the link.

Why would this be, and what can I do to switch back to normal behavior?

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue, but with Apple Mail, not Thunderbird or Outlook. I ended up quitting both of them and restarting my MacBook. That took care of the issue. This only affected Google Chrome though; if I changed the default browser to Safari, links opened properly while they didn't in Google Chrome. I'm guessing some update to Google Chrome caused this behavior that required a system restart to correct, but that's a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer. ***BUT***: after a restart this morning (for some updates), clicking on links in Thunderbird and Outlook correctly load in my default browser (Chrome).